# Dependency Tracking function in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

At *Vue.js Advanced Features from the Ground Up* Evan gave a little task.

> - Create a `Dep` class with two methods: `depend` and `notify`.
> - Create an `autorun` function that takes an updater function.
> - Inside the updater function, you can explicitly depend on an instance of `Dep` by calling `dep.depend()`
> - Later, you can trigger the updater function to run again by calling `dep.notify()`.

The full usage should look like this:

```
const dep = new Dep()
autorun(() => {
  dep.depend()
  console.log('updated')
})
// should log: "updated"

dep.notify()
// should log: "updated"
```

The idea of that task was to show logic of dependency in Vue.

**Solution**

```
<script>
// a class representing a dependency
// exposing it on window is necessary for testing
window.Dep = class Dep {
    constructor () {
      this.subscribers = new Set()
    }
    depend () {
      if (activeUpdate) {
        // register the current active update as a subscriber
        this.subscribers.add(activeUpdate)
      }
    }
    notify () {
      // run all subscriber functions
      this.subscribers.forEach(subscriber => subscriber())
    }
}
let activeUpdate
function autorun (update) {
  function wrappedUpdate () {
    activeUpdate = wrappedUpdate
    update()
    activeUpdate = null
  }
  wrappedUpdate()
}
</script>
```

I can't get why do we use `activeUpdate` and `wrappedUpdate` in the code. Evan explained that

> We're registering `wrappedUpdate` as `activeUpdate`, so that when our dependency changes and `update` function is called again we're in fact calling `wrappedUpdate` again. We need to make asure that our little dependecy trick is still working on future iterations, and it keeps collecting all dependencies. This is important, cause in some cases our `update` function may contain conditionals (if `true` - this dependency, if `false` - the other). Our dependency collecting system should dynamically rebalance and always keep dependencies up to date.

Can anyone explain how does it work?

Comment: I find the use of `activeUpdate` confusing since it's declared after `Dep`, and [let is not subject to hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we have no hoisting/temporal dead zone issue here. Since, `dep.depend()` will always find `activeUpdate` variable in Global Scope, unless we call that method before declaration of that variable.

> **Why `activeUpdate`?**

For proper dependency tracking we need a tool to indicate that we are inside the function which is currently running. That is the point of using `activeUpdate` variable - to signal that we are inside `wrappedUpdate` function and we are about to update our dependencies.

> **Why `wrappedFunction`**?

We want to perfom that check for new subscriber whenever our dependency changes and `update` function is called. It looks like a chain of calls:

> *notify --> wrappedUpdate --> dep.depend()*

and via `activeUpdate` we check whether our dependency has been changed or not due to some conditionals. If it has - we register it in *subscriber `Set`*, if it is already in `Set` - we ignore adding.